# Git rebase strange behavior while squashing

Tags: git

```
78150e8 o
cee2a86 u
9245122 R
648e939 G
51f9c17 R
ec231e7 A
c6d8821 (
69929c8 r
069066e M
716effb E
6059871 R
b28652d D
```

My 'git log' look like this. However, when I do git rebase -i ec231e7, I see this:

```
pick 51f9c17 R
pick 648e939 G
pick 9245122 R
pick 87da37f a
pick dd75331 M
pick 79d39a7 g
pick 1da0ff3 f
pick 2ff243c a
pick 9803d09 f
pick 3704efe h
pick 416bdc2 u
pick 24fb08a r
pick b28652d D
pick 6059871 R
pick 716effb E
pick 069066e M
pick 69929c8 r
pick c6d8821 r
pick cee2a86 u
pick 050e86f s
```

It seems to not only have mixed up the order of a few commits, but also pulled commits that are not from the same branch. Why?

Update:git log --oneline ec231e7

```
ec231e7 A
088dae1 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) environments
830daaf g
000c2e7 c
3378fe2 r
af79a23 f
7969e31 u
052a5c8 r
97764b1 C
a69df91 s
03c9ab7 r
8d2a249 a
992a62d M
5caa332 s
5614c9b U
```

Comment: Try `git rebase --interactive 'ec231e7^'`

Comment: What's the output of `git log --oneline ec231e7..`? You can run `git log --oneline --graph` to see the real history graph.

Comment: @J.Smith Why the quotes?

Comment: I prefer using quotes where I put my user entry, in case of uses of shell interpreted characters like $, !, *, spaces and so on, but here, they are unnecessary.

Comment: @J.Smith same issue

Comment: You must have a merge commit in that list. See ElpieKay's comment.

Comment: Remember to use the `—graph` flag to see the true commit history.